# WooCommerce, how to remove downloadable products permission for order

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to remove the permission to download the files of certain orders (even if already paid), e.g. if customer payment gets revoked.

I am fiddling around with "wc_downloadable_file_permission" but somehow this only grants permission, but I want to revoke it.

I even tried to manually handle wp_posts_meta (_download_permissions_granted:yes/no) but it did not work.

So far i got this.

```
function revoke_download_permission( $order_id ) {    
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) { 
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) { 
        $product = $item->get_product(); 

        if ( $product && $product->exists() && $product->is_downloadable() ) { 
            $downloads = $product->get_downloads(); 

            foreach ( array_keys( $downloads ) as $download_id ) { 
                wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $product, $order, $item->get_quantity() ); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Pass 0 instead $item->get_quantity() in the function

Comment: Thank you. But this does not revoke download permissions. This only adds an additional record in table wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions with value downloads_remaining=0. This still lets the customer download the file. I will dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, i got it.

Instead of completely removing the download permission I set the value of remaining downloads to zero which has the same effect. And if customer pays you can still set the value back to it's default value.

```
function revoke_download_permission( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) { 
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) { 
            $product = $item->get_product(); 

            if ( $product && $product->exists() && $product->is_downloadable() ) { 
                $downloads = $product->get_downloads(); 

                foreach ( array_keys( $downloads ) as $download_id ) { 

                    $wpdb->update( 
                        'wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions', 
                        array( 
                            'downloads_remaining' => '0'
                        ), 
                        array( 'download_id' => $download_id )
                    );                    
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Juergen's solution is not consistent with WooCommerce's new datastore mechanism as of this writing.  Additionally, it does not remove download permissions from the download-permission database that do not have a corresponding order.

Here's an improved solution for regenerating all download permissions in bulk, that addresses these issues as well.  The below is consistent with the "Regenerate download permissions" command in WooCommerce, but it is applied to all completed orders.

Put this in your functions.php file, load the wp-admin page, and then remove it from functions.php.

Obvious caveat: THIS WILL DELETE ALL DOWNLOAD PERMISSIONS FOR YOUR SITE before regenerating them.  If you've manually assigned permissions to any customer for any product, those will be hosed and made consistent with your order database.  Use totally at your own risk, no warranties expressed or implied.

```
add_action('init','my_activate_download_permissions');
function my_activate_download_permissions() {

$orders = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => 'wc-completed',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'customer-download' );
    $data_store->delete_by_order_id( $order->ID );
    wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order->ID, true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After search for a whole day, found a solution to do this with a query in MYSQL (i used 5.7)  (big thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen)

To delete all permission downloads from selected ORDERS ID:

```sql
DELETE
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE `order_id` IN (ORDER ID1, ORDER ID2, ...);
```

If you want to delete permission for all refunded orders:

```sql
DELETE
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted didn't suit my needs. This is the way I would do it, it actually deletes the download permissions from the order directly.

```
function revoke_download_permissions( $order_id, $product_id )
{
        $data_store = new WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store;
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0) {
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                $product = $item->get_product();
                if ( $product && $product->exists() && $product->is_downloadable() ) {
                    if ( $product->get_id() == $product_id) {
                        $downloads = $product->get_downloads();
                        foreach ( $downloads as $d ) { 
                            $data_store->delete_by_download_id( $d->get_id() );
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
}
```