# Regenerating WooCommerce Download Permissions on older orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add some download permissions to all previous orders via a script to do them in batch. The script seems to work fine expect for one thing. Here is the script…

```
function update_download_permissions(){

  $orders = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => 'wc-completed',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  ) );

  foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order->ID, true );
  }

}
```

The problem is the wc_downloadable_product_permissions function is producing duplicate entries in the wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions table.

I tried to set the second argument to false (the default) but that resulted in no permissions being created.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why duplicate download permissions are being set?

Cheers!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375583/512923 for how I dealt with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question after digging through some of the WooCommerce source code, while attempting to add an item to an existing order and then regenerate the permissions.

The reason `wc_downloadable_product_permissions()` will create duplicate permission entries is because it does not check for any existing permissions. It simply inserts another entry into the permissions table for every item in the order, which is no good because this will then show up as another download in both the admin and user account frontend.

The second `force` parameter (poorly documented), is related to a boolean flag that indicates whether `wc_downloadable_product_permissions()` has run before. The boolean is set to true at the end of the function via the set_download_permissions_granted method. If `force` is true, it will ignore the boolean. If `force` is false, and the boolean is true, the function will return near the start.

I created this function which uses the same functions as used by the admin Order action "Regenerate download permissions":

```
/**
 * Regenerate the WooCommerce download permissions for an order
 * @param  Integer $order_id
 */
function regen_woo_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id ){

    // Remove all existing download permissions for this order.
    // This uses the same code as the "regenerate download permissions" action in the WP admin (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.5.2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-actions.php#L129-L131)
    // An instance of the download's Data Store (WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store) is created and
    // uses its method to delete a download permission from the database by order ID.
    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'customer-download' );
    $data_store->delete_by_order_id( $order_id );

    // Run WooCommerce's built in function to create the permissions for an order (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_downloadable_product_permissions.html)
    // Setting the second "force" argument to true makes sure that this ignores the fact that permissions
    // have already been generated on the order.
    wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id, true );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I should have added in my original question that there are no download permissions in the database before I run the code.  I had deleted all permissions first (of course this is a sandbox site ;) ).  So it isn't adding one more, it is in fact adding two new rows.

Comment: In that case, my only guess would be that `wc_downloadable_product_permissions()` is running twice; this still should work since it would delete and re-add on the second run. If that's not the case, I would check the output of $product->get_downloads() on one of the products (WC_Product method, you can use wc_get_product to get an instance). The source is running `wc_downloadable_file_permission()` (note: singular) on each array item returned by that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to update order download is to hook into the `save_post` action hook and check if it's a product that's being updated
there you can get order ids by product id and update just orders that relate to that specific product.
it's more efficient

```
function get_orders_ids_by_product_id($product_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";
    return $wpdb->get_col(
        "
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim, 
             {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi, 
             {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        WHERE  woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        AND woi.order_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
        ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC"
    );
}

// if you don't add 3 as as 4th argument, this will not work as expected
add_action('save_post', 'prefix_on_post_update', 10, 3);

function prefix_on_post_update($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
        $orders_ids = get_orders_ids_by_product_id($post_id);
        foreach ($orders_ids as $order_id) {
            $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load('customer-download');
            $data_store->delete_by_order_id($order_id);
            wc_downloadable_product_permissions($order_id, true);
        }
    }
}
```