# How do I bulk generate download permissions on WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a downloadable product, with over 2000 customers buying it so far. While updating the downloadable product, removed access to the current 2000+ clients resulting in many confused emails. The customers are still shown as buying the digital product in their account purchases.
how do I bulk generate/grant download permissions on WooCommerce to the customers that have already bought my downloadable product?

and, I would like this option to be available only to registered users.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://jboullion.com/regenerate-woocommerce-download-permissions/

https://codedcommerce.com/product/bulk-regenerate-download-permissions/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553478/regenerating-woocommerce-download-permissions-on-older-orders

Comment: unfortunately, these solutions only reset the date, and do not add downloads again, I knew something like that

https://andrewrminion.com/2017/12/woocommerce-downloadable-products-granting-permissions-to-previous-customers/

Comment: I think the best way is to write a simple code for that instead going for a plugin!